# Youtube API v3 return wrong response

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a problem with the YouTube API version 3. If I upload a video with foreign rights (e.g. a video of Windows ) , I get the reponse "duplicate" from YouTube that the video already exists in my account. But that isn't correct, because I have never uploaded that video before.

I expect as response "copyright" from YouTube. Is that an error in the API?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error that you are encountering? And if possible your implementation too.

Comment: I think the error is not in the code, because after the upload I get as response for the state "rejected" and the reason is "duplicate". In YouTube I see in the section "video-manager" that video is marked as "rejected" with the reason "copyright".